# C++ why we include all declarations in header files

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
```

When you do this and it becomes the source passing through the preprocessor, our file will be 5k. The compiler doesn't do all this declaration, right? (There are always some things we don't use after all)

| Is the linker or compiler preventing this?

Comment: You can have a million declarations.  If they are not used, they are immaterial.

Comment: For template declarations, unless the template is explicitly specialized than only the specializations you need are generated. So if you don't use any, there are no specializations. For non-template declarations it doesn't matter if you include the header or not. The symbols will be imported during compilation simply by including the library in your build. The only harm extra headers can do is slow compilation down. Anyway, good compilers are capable of removing unused symbols from when configured to do so.

Comment: @Eljay so if the things that I declared in the code are not used
the compiler ignores it right?

Comment: @PyroSoft Define "used". The compiler definitely sees a lot of declarations form the included header, and will parse them, type-check them, etc. (this might be optimized through pre-compiled headers, but it does not really matter). However, if they are not used later on, these declarations won't affect the generated executable file. In this sense, they are ignored.

Answer (score -1):

**so when you include all declaration file in header **

1. improve build times.
2. link against code without having the source for the definitions.
3. avoid marking everything "inline".

> compiler only see the declaration as it know definition might be somewhere , then it use all definition at the linking time.

Comment: The question is not why declarations are included, but why **all** declarations are included, and how compilers/linkers deal with the not used code of the header.

Answer (score -1):

The rule of thumb is this: Header files should contain declarations, source files should contain definitions.

Two types of Declarations:

1. DECLARATIONS: A declaration introduces a name into a scope. Generally speaking, a scope is either an entire .cpp file or anything in code delimited by {}, be it a function, a loop within a function, or even an arbitrarily placed block of {} within a function. A name introduced, is visible within the scope from the point at which it is declared to the end of that scope. A declarations merely tells the compiler how to use something, it does not actually create anything.

```
    extern int y; // declares y, but does not define it.  y is defined elsewhere,
                  // but the program can now use it since it knows what it is (an integer)
```

2. PROTOTYPES: A prototype is just another name for a declaration of a function.

```
    double someFunction( double, int );
```

referred from :
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/yAqpX9L8/

Also get more information on this site:
http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/Gw6AC542/

Comment: This is rather simplistic. Class definitions, for example, belong in header files.